# LEGO Mindstorms NXT - NXC compiler for OS X

Tags: mindstorms

I need an IDE for LEGO Mindstorms on my Mac, but I only found a few for Linux and Windows but not for Mac. I found NeXT Tools, but the newest version isn't compatible with Yosemite. If I execute it, it will throw an error, so I need some compiler for Yosemite.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use XCode. You need to download the [NXC compiler](http://bricxcc.sourceforge.net/nbc/release/index.html) (the linked page says NBC, but it included NXC as well). Then, write a Makefile that calls the NXC compiler.

If the compiler does not work on Yosemite, the source code is available from that link as well.

A detailed tutorial on using XCode with NXC can be found [here](http://mastincrosbie.com/Marks_LEGO_projects/NXC_in_Xcode_3_on_Mac_OS_10.5.html).